# regex search from starting to ending string

Tags: regex, pycharm

I'm using pycharm and want to search in code using regex. I want to filter those files that has 2 lines. One after another.

What I'm trying to accomplish is find code where is code line `_inherit = 'res.partner` and `unique_code` afterwards:

```
_inherit = 'res.partner' 

parent_company = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Parent Company')   
unique_code = fields.Char(string='Unique client code', readonly="1",copy=False, index=True)
```

So far what I have manage to do is: `_inherit = 'res.partner'\s*.` select first data point and all white space that goes after.

How can select `unique_code` also?

Comment: Is this what you want: `unique_code =.*`.

Comment: do you just want to jump over the `parent_company` line? You can match entire lines that you don't want with `[^\n]*\n` (any-number of non-newline characters followed by a newline character).

Comment: And want to find text where there is: 
[A] flowed with [B]. 
For example 1)[A]CCCCCC - not selected 2) [A]QWEQW[B] - selected

Comment: Does `_inherit = 'res\.partner'(?s:.*?)unique_code.*` help? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qo9wsz/2).

Comment: I posted the answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
_inherit = 'res\.partner'(?s:.*?)unique_code.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qo9wsz/2).

*Details*:

- `_inherit = 'res\.partner'` - a `_inherit = 'res.partner'` string
- `(?s:.*?)` -  any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `unique_code` -  a literal text
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.